# Cation falling off electrode after electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I'm trying to find the electrochemical equivalent for zinc in an experiment. 
I am carrying out electrolysis of zinc sulfate solution. 
According to Faraday's law, m=zq.
I made a 0.1 M solution and kept time for electrolysis constant (1 min). 
To get a value for z I plotted the mass over the charge (I*t). The current was varied. I'm getting a linear trend (mass deposited increases with increase in current) but a huge discrepancy of 100%.
Also in the experiment, after the electrolysis I noticed that the zinc separated and got suspended in the solution when I disconnected the electrode to measure the new mass. This could have affected results.
Any reasons for this? I might be able to redo the experiment if someone knows how I can solve this or get better results.
The metal ions should undergo reduction at the cathode. Maybe that's not happening?

P.s I also did it for copper sulfate and it was worse. Almost no copper stayed on the electrode after electrolysis 
Also I used graphite electrodes for this. Before this, for another experiment I electroplated zinc with copper and all of it deposited. Maybe get better results with zinc/copper electrodes for this experiment instead of graphite?

Regards,
Haseeb

Comment: Try reducing the *current density*, by increasing the electrode's size or by reducing current.

Comment: @Gert But I am already varying current from 1 to 5 A in steps of 1A. But do you think it would be possible to the same experiment and get the same relationship if I use copper electrodes instead of graphite. Because I didn't get an issue with the copper electrodes.

Comment: $5\ \mathrm{A}$ is very high current for a 0.1 M solution. Graphite really isn't suitable. Better use the respective metals.

Comment: Ok, I will try that then. Do you know if the relationship still holds, m=zQ? (keeping time constant of course.)

Comment: Yes, of course. Faraday's Law, basically.